# What are Bottcher coordinates useful for?

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-equations, complex-dynamics

I've been reading about [Bottcher coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%B6ttcher%27s_equation) lately, and I've seen them in fundamental books like Milnor's and Hubbard's. Although I can see the benefit of semiconjugating a map to a nicer map, I'm not sure of actual results that have been proven using Bottcher coordinates or how one would actually go about using them.

Does anyone have any references for results (the more fundamental or easier to understand, the better) that use Bottcher coordinates?

Comment: For those like me that hadn't the faintest idea of what the Bottcher coordinates are : http://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~mases/Bottcher.pdf

Comment: Yup! I am also specifically interested in Bottcher coordinates at infinity, but any information would be useful.

Comment: to add a bit to Claude's answer, Böttcher coordinates give you information on the Julia set, because the Julia set is exactly the boundary of the basin of infinity. So at least philosophically, the idea is to try to take limits $|\zeta| \to 1$ in Böttcher coordinates in order to say something about the Julia set. This leads to the notion of external rays, and to the question of when you can extend continuously Böttcher coordinates on the unit circle

Answer (score 2):

[External rays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_ray) are important in the study of the Mandelbrot set and Julia sets.

I once made a commutative diagram to aid my understanding of how the smoothed escape time and exterior distance estimates are calculated for Julia sets of $z \to z^p + c$, using $\phi_c \approx \operatorname{id}$ near $\infty$:

[image: commutative diagram]